# Two groups overlapping by a fixed number

Tags: combinatorics

A travel agency offers the chance to its customers to win vouchers for 2 free excursions during the Covid crisis. Out of the x total customers, y will be randomly chosen to participate in the first excursion and z in the second. In how many of all possible draws we will have a total of w customers who will participate in both excursions?

I am not sure about the exact interpretation: Let's say we have 25 customers and we randomly choose 8 for the first and 7 for the second. If 3 of them are in both excursions (that is, if the 2 groups have 3 people in common), then we have a total of 3 people who will participate in both excursions.
The first draw gives us $xCy$ and the second $xCz$. Obviously it must be $w \leq y+z$.

Can anyone help? I am not good at combinatorics!
(This is a puzzle just for challenging between friends - not an assignment or anything.)

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the lucky $w$ first in $\binom{x}{w}$ ways, then from the remainder $x-w$ you choose the ones that were in the first excursion in $\binom{x-w}{y-w}$ and now from the $x-y$ people that are not going to the first excursion, you pick the $z-w$ in $\binom{x-y}{z-w}$ ways so
$$\binom{x}{w}\binom{x-w}{y-w}\binom{x-y}{z-w}.$$

Answer (score 0):

There are $3$ distinct groups: $(y-w)$ for only excursion $1$, $w$ for both excursions, and $(z-w)$ for only excursion $2$

Use permutations with repetitions to get  $\,\dfrac{x!}{(y-w)!\,(w)!\,(z-w)!}$

*The above assumes that all $x$ people get at least one excursion.* If this is not true, there is a fourth group of $u$ people who don't get any excursion, and the formula becomes$\,\dfrac{x!}{(y-w)!\,(w)!\,(z-w)!(u)!}$